# rails3 app using gem 'spine-rails' (0.0.9)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spine.js

I created sample rails3 app using gem `spine-rails` (0.0.9) to implement spine.js.

I dont know how to create relationship (belongs_to,has_many) using spine-rails.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume you are using rails 3.1

Relation.js is not as default of Spine `core` component. so you need add it yourself. just add  `#= require spine/relation` after `#= require spine/route`

app/assets/javascripts/app/index.js.coffee:

```
#= require json2
#= require jquery
#= require spine
#= require spine/manager
#= require spine/ajax
#= require spine/route
#= require spine/relation

#= require_tree ./lib
#= require_self
#= require_tree ./models
#= require_tree ./controllers
#= require_tree ./views
```